# Question about aurifeullian factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

> For which perfect powers $\ b>1\ $ can the expression $$\frac{b^{p^2}-1}{b^p-1}$$ be a prime number , if $\ p\ $ is prime ?

If $\ b>1\ $ is a perfect power , then $\ b=a^k\ $ for some integers $\ a,k>1\ $.

So we get $$\frac{a^{kp^2}-1}{a^{kp}-1}$$

and if the polynomial $$f(x)=\frac{x^{kp^2}-1}{x^{kp}-1}$$ is reducible we (probably) will get aurifeullian factors. It seems that in most cases, we get an irreducible polynomial. Who can shed some light on this ?

Comment: Let $X=x^{kp}-1$. Then $f(x)=[(X+1)^p-1]/X$ and Eisenstein ensures that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It's not the case that $g(X)$ being irreducible implies that $g(x^{kp}-1)$ is irreducible, as the example $g(X)=X$ shows.

Comment: @GregMartin Hm, well $f(x)=\Phi_p(x^{kp})$ and IIRC $\Phi$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: More generally, $g(X)$ being irreducible does not imply that $g(h(x))$ is irreducible when $h(x)$ has degree at least $2$. Furthermore, there are ample counterexamples to the conclusion that $f(x)$ is irreducible, as one can find by hand or as I point out in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The irreducible factorization of $x^m-1$ (over $\Bbb Z$) is the product of the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(x)$ over all positive integers $d$ dividing $m$. So the irreducible factorization of $f(x)$ is the product of the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(x)$ over all positive integers $d$ that divide $kp^2$ but not $kp$.

Assuming for simplicity that $p$ doesn't divide $k$: these integers $d$ are precisely those of the form $bp^2$ where $b$ divides $k$; in particular, there is more than one such integer when $k>1$, and so $f(x)$ will *not* be irreducible. (The assumption that $p$ doesn't divide $k$ can be weakened to $k$ not being a power of $p$.)

Comment: So, can we conclude that we can get a prime only if $k$ is a power of $p$ ?